# Finding a function based on their limits

Tags: limits, functions

I have points and limits of a function and even the shape of the function and I'm looking for the function, something that very interesting for me how could I control the curve of the function?

(1) $\lim\limits_{x \to inf} f(x) = 1 $

(2) $f(\frac{1}{c}) = 1 $

(3) $0\lt x$

(4) $0\lt c \leq 1$

[image: Shape of function]

Answer (score 4):

One such function is $1-(1-c^{2}x^{2})^{+}$ where $y^{+}$ denotes $\max \{y,0 \}$.

Edit: this function is convex on $(0,\frac 1 c)$. To make it concave consider $\min \{1, \frac {1-e^{-cx}} {1-e^{-1}} \}$.

Comment: Is the limit at infinity $1$ ?

Comment: Yes, this function has the value $1$ for all $x>\frac 1 c$. @FareedAF

Comment: When I plot your function I get some other shape.

Comment: @DSaad You are right. I have edited my answer.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vq4nfceokl I ploted it and then in lim→ ()=1.57

Comment: @DSaad You forgot to take the minimum with $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I found two answers after a lot of experimenting with variables:

$\left(\frac{\left(e^{2\cdot e\cdot c\cdot x}\right)-1}{\left(e^{2\cdot e\cdot c\cdot x}\right)+1}\right)$

$\left(\frac{1-\left(e^{-2\cdot e\cdot c\cdot x}\right)}{1+\left(e^{-2\cdot e\cdot c\cdot x}\right)}\right)$

You can see the plots and play with c here: [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0tqfumlp4x)

Answer (score -1):

This function satisfies all conditions except one of them, but maybe it'll help you, try $f(x)= -\frac{1}{x+1} +1$

Comment: $\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{\left(c\right)^2\cdot x+1}\right)\right)$ I changed it a little bit but still I have problem for condition 2.